# Python and Pandas: How count a column with specific condition

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm new in Pandas with Python, and I want to ask for help with something that I think is easy for someone more experienced than me.

I have a LOG file, where this file has a few columns. These columns can have different states.

I think an example is better:

```
ID | ANSWER | DETAIL | .. | OTHERS
12345 | Complete | Answer_OK | .. | whatever
12346 | Incomplete | Answer_NOK | .. | whatever
12345 | Complete | Answer_NOK | .. | whatever
```

Then, I need to count the "ID" records when Answer = Incomplete, but not count when the "ID" has "Answer_OK" and at the same time have "Answer_NOK".

In excel is pretty easy, because you create a dynamic table and a new column you put an IF sentence that checks `(IF A1 > 0 and A2 > 0, 0, 1)`, and later you sum the new column and have the number, but in Pandas, I can't make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .loc[] function for this. For example for what you are trying to do you would do
`df = df.loc[df["answer"]=="Incomplete"]`  Then on the next line you would just do that again for the other values you want `df = df.loc[df["details"]=="Answer_NOK"]`
then df would equal the dataframe you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = your_dataframe

df_grouped = df.groupby(["ID"]).aggregate({"ANSWER":list, "DETAIL":list}).reset_index()
mask = df_grouped["ANSWER"].map(lambda x: "Incomplete" in x) & ~(df_grouped["DETAIL"].map(lambda x: "Answer_OK" in x) & df_grouped["DETAIL"].map(lambda x: "Answer_NOK" in x))

print(np.sum(mask))
```

Your Id is not unique therefore you can group the dataframe first (like excel pivot table) and get a list of value which the id has for "ANSWER" and "DETAIL".
Then you have a new dataframe where the ID is unique. With this dataframe you can create a series consiting of True / False answering your filter requirements.

Then you can use numpy to calculate the sum of "True" in this series.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer you give me is 0.
I read that is better to avoid the iteration in Pandas, but sincerely I think that could be the best option... :/

Comment: The code should work, but it depends on ur data, it is very helpful if you coudl provide a [mre] meaning, input + what u trid and failed + expected output